# Push div to top after changing position of other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please help me here.
I have 3 UL in my page.
UL 1 variable height
UL 2 variable height
UL 3 variable height
now suppose if I want to push ul 2 to middle of screen such that ul 1 goes to top automatically & only part of ul 1 is visible in the screen.I mean say, UL 1 may be 1 to 50 % and ul 2 may 50 to ..... of screen height.Pls help me in implementing this.

```
<div> FUTURE </div>
<ul>
<li> List 1 </li>
<li> List 2 </li>
<li> List 3 </li>
.......
</ul>

<div> TODAY </div>
<ul>
<li> List 1 </li>
<li> List 2 </li>
<li> List 3 </li>
.......
</ul>

<div> PAST </div>
<ul>
<li> List 1 </li>
<li> List 2 </li>
<li> List 3 </li>
.......
</ul>
```

All 3 can be present in a page. Assume future records exceeds the height of page, in this scenario, I want to push TODAY block to center of screen & future to top.I have implemented iScroll for the entire page & is woring fine. I am  stuck how to push TODAY block to center of screen so that FUTURE data automatically goes up.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: @emmanuel please find the code

Answer (score 0):

use z-index check this example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).hope it helps